# Requests library raises ConnectionError if web-server returns error but only when uploading large file

Tags: python, python-requests, httpresponse, bottle

I'm running a webserver based on the Bottle framework. This framework exposes an endpoint where you can upload a file. Sometimes, if the disk is full, the webserver is supposed to return a code 429 without reading the file. For some reason, when I'm uploading a file, if the server tries to return a 429 status code the following exception is raised:

```
 File "../hooks.py", line 325, in post_video_content
    response = requests.post(url, data=fh)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 110, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 56, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 473, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```

But if try the exact same post but instead of posting a file I simply post some small amount of data, I actually get a response object back from the request and I can inspect the status code.

To reproduce:

webserver.py

```
from bottle import Bottle, route, run, request, response, get, post, put, abort

@post('/content')
@authenticate
def content():
    response.status = 429
    return "failed to write incoming movie to temp file (space might be full temporarily)"

run(host="127.0.0.1", port=8080, debug=True)
```

send_request.py

```
import requests


# this works and prints the status code
ret = requests.post("127.0.0.1:8080/content", data="sdfsdfsdfsdf")
print ret.status_code

# this part will throw an exception
try:
    with open("~/some_large_video_file.mp4", 'rb') as fh:
        ret = requests.post('127.0.0.1:8080/content', data=fh)
except:
    print traceback.format_exc()
```

EDIT - I've found out that it depends on the amount of data. If you try and post something like 10KB of data we get the 429 return code. I'm trying to figure out what the limit is that causes it to start raising an exception.

EDIT2 - So it looks like the magic filesize is somewhere between 117K and 131K. If I try the former it works as intended, I get the response from the request and can access the status code. If I try the former I get the exception raised.

My questions are:

1. Why does this happen? Is it a bug in bottle? A bug in requests? Why would the size/type of data I'm posting change the response?
2. Is there any way to get around this? I'm trying to associate a `ConnectionError` exception with the server being down, and a 429 response code meaning the disk is full. If I'm getting the same exception for both I can't tell the difference between the situations which blocks me from implementing a back-off to wait for disk space to open up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I cross-posted this to the requests github issue page, and it looks like the issue is in the `httplib` module that requests is built on top of, so this is a no-fix for now.

see: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/4062

Comment: It won't let me for another day or so